# Simple java program to do canopy cluster strings based on their values

Tags: java, string, cluster-analysis

I want to know how to cluster this input using canopy cluster in java?

```
       1 access 375
       1 addition 375
       1 advance 375
       1 answered 375
       1 applied 375
       1 approximate 375
       1 evil 375

       1 hiway 375
       1 home 375
       1 hope 375
       1 hotmail 375
       3 town 375
       4 forum 375
       4 good 375
       4 reig 375
       5 plot 375
```

In which first column is frequency of the word. 2nd column is the word and third column is the total number of words.

How to do canopy sorting? and want to know what is threashold values?

Comment: I don't know the canopy sorting. Could you explain what the output should be?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canopy_clustering_algorithm and https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAHOUT/Canopy+Clustering

Comment: thus any one have any idea of how to do canopy clustering over this data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Canopy clustering is applied to *vectors* and to *complete texts*, not to *single words*.

What do you consider a cluster to be? Unless you are clear about what you *expect* a cluster to be like, you are never going to figure out what the right algorithm is.

So do you expect a cluster like:

```
   1 access 375
   1 addition 375
   1 advance 375
   1 answered 375
   1 applied 375
   1 approximate 375
```

(Rare words starting with a)? Is this of any use to you?

Clustering algorithms are not magic tools. You need to carefully choose and configure them to produce the kind of result that you are interested in.

Comment: Can you say me an example how the input vectors for canopy clustering is to be? 

[hello,helloworld,40,goodnight]
[hellosir,helloworld,42,goodmorning]
[hellohi,helloworld,44,goodevening]

Comment: Try TF-IDF vectors. Note that it won't be clustering words, but documents.